# How to get order ID after placing order with rest API

Tags: orders, magento2.3, rest-api

How can we get the `increment_id` when you finish a order as a login customer?

I try to get the `increment_id` to show in a succes page but the only ID I'm receving is the `order_id` after I've made the `/payment-information` with the rest API.

My workflow is this one:

- get the customer token `/V1/integration/customer/token`
- create a cart `/V1/carts/mine`
- add item to the cart `/V1/carts/mine/items`
- add shipping information `/V1/carts/mine/shipping-information`
- Add billing information and process checkout `/V1/carts/mine/payment-information`

Answer (score 0):

If you have an admin token available use

> /V1/orders/

to get increment_id. If not, create a new endpoint that will translate order id to increment id if the currently authenticated user is the one that placed it.

Comment: But if I'm loaged as a customer with a customer token?